# Set node action for specific content type

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I want to set a trigger to redirect when a node (or comment) on a certain content-type is created.

I have 2 hurdles here:

1. The Trigger module doesn't seem to offer any distinction between content types. Will I have to write some sort of hook?
2. I can create an action to redirect to the specific URL, but it always shows up under the 'system' category and is then not in the dropdown list when I go to set it for creation of every content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module will be able to handle this, it's a next-generation version of the actions/triggers that are included with core:

> The rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

You can use the "After saving a new comment" event for the comments part, and the "After saving new content" event for the content part.

In both cases you'll be able to use conditions on your rules to make sure the actions are only fired for your required content types.